# ReportViewer gives "Specified argument out of range" error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a simple bar graph that I created in 2005 and I have uploaded this to reporting services 2005 and used the ReportViewer control to place this within my visual studio 2005 web page.

The web page works perfectly fine without the report viewer contol on the page.

In my web page I have added the following code:

```xml
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```

and I have the report viewer here:

```xml
<rsweb:reportviewer id="rptViewer11" runat="server" processingmode="Remote" showfindcontrols="False" height="246px" width="380px" showtoolbar="False" sizetoreportcontent="True">
      <ServerReport  reportpath="/foldername" reportserverurl="http://server/" />
</rsweb:reportviewer>
```

The report works fine in reporting services and in the the web page it launchs fine and produces the bar graph . It has also been set a refresh rate in SSRS 2005 of 90 seconds.

The problem that I have is that intermittently an error msg box is produced that states:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

It's worth noting that the bar graph is produced by a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Do you have JavaScript debugging enabled in your browser?

Comment: No i dont.  Im pretty new to .net and dont know much about javascript.

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to complete this query.  I have got rid of the report viewer in my web page and created a control that holds the report viewer.  This control has then been added to my web page and the report renders fine.  The refresh rate that i have set in place also refreshes the image / report quicker than before.